# How to dry wet sugar?

Tags: sugar

How to dry sugar when it gets wet?

Comment: Jane, we need more details: how much sugar, how wet, wet with water or something else...?

Answer (score 3):

If the sugar is just damp -not wet beach sand- tip it through a sieve/strainer gently enough to catch the clumps. These lumps can be air-dried in a shallow layer (not humid conditions) then once again into a strainer and rubbed through to separate. Or just enjoy the homemade 'cubes' with your tea.

Answer (score 0):

Drying out the sugar and passing it through a food processor can return the granularity of it.

Comment: The question: "**How** to dry sugar..."

Comment: I spread mine out on a baking sheet less than 1/4 inch (5 mm) deep and put it in the oven at 180 (low as mine goes)(82c) for 10 minutes then sifted with strainer while warm onto a piece of newspaper to cool.   The paper made it easier to put it in an airtight container once dry.

Comment: My sugar was not very damp so you may need to bake longer. When spreading it on paper it shouldn't be more than 1/8in  (1-2mm) deep.  Also,  don't try anything (except perhaps rice in a sealed container) if the humidity is high in your kitchen.

Comment: Also, electric ovens work better than gas. It will likely take longer in a gas oven since gas raises the humidity.